# Win32 File Name Comparison

Tags: winapi, case-insensitive

Does anyone know what culture settings Win32 uses when dealing with case-insensitive files names?

Is this something that varies based on the user's culture, or are the casing rules that Win32 uses culture invariant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An approximate answer is at
[Comparing Unicode file names the right way](http://web.archive.org/web/20130528052217/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/michkap/archive/2005/10/17/481600.aspx).

Basically, the recommendation is to uppercase both strings (using [`CharUpper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647474(v=vs.85).aspx), [`CharUpperBuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647475(v=vs.85).aspx), or [`LCMapString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318700(v=vs.85).aspx)), then compare using a binary comparison (i.e. memcmp or wmemcmp, not CompareString with an invariant locale). The file system doesn't do Unicode normalization, and the case rules are not dependent on locale settings.

There are unfortunate ambiguous cases when dealing with characters whose casing rules have changed across different versions of Unicode, but it's about as good as you can do.

Answer (score 6):

[Comparing file names in native code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/greggm/comparing-file-names-in-native-code) and [Don't compare filenames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/greggm/dont-compare-file-names) are a couple of good blog posts on this topic.   The first has C/C++ code for OrdinalIgnoreCaseCompareStrings, and the second tells you how that doesn't always work for filenames and what to do to mitigate that.

> Then there are the Unicode problems. While these new `OrdinalIgnoreCase` string comparison algorithms are great for your local NTFS drive, they might not yield the right answer on your FAT drive, or a network share.
>
> So what's the answer? When possible, let the file system tell you. [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/fileio/fs/createfile.asp) can tell you if a given filename exists. Just pick the right creation disposition. If you need to compare to handles, you can often use [`GetFileInformationByHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/fileio/fs/getfileinformationbyhandle.asp); look at `dwVolumeSerialNumber`/`nFileIndexHigh`/`nFileIndexLow`.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **.NET**, the official recommendation from Microsoft is to use [`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) for comparison and [`ToUpperInvariant`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant.aspx) for normalization (to be later compared using `Ordinal` comparison). This also applies to Registry keys and values, environment variables etc.

See [New Recommendations for Using Strings in Microsoft .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx) for more details.

Note that while it's reliable on NTFS, it can fail with network shares, for example. See @SteveSteiner's answer and links in his post for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Windows Driver Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys) FastFAT and CDFS, it uses `RtlUpcaseUnicodeString` to convert a string to uppercase.  According to a brief look in Ghidra, that uses an internal function named `NLS_UPCASE`, whose behavior is **based on your current system codepage**.